# How to show $\phi $ is an injective map?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, complex-analysis, functions, gelfand-representation

[image]

I'm trying to show that $\phi$ is an injective map for this i'm trying to show $\phi(t_1)=\phi(t_2)\implies t_1=t_2$

let $$\phi(t_1)=\phi(t_2)$$ $$\implies \varphi_{t_1}=\varphi_{t_2}$$ $$\implies \varphi_{t_1}(f)=\varphi_{t_2}(f)\forall f\in C^n[a,b]$$ $$\implies f({t_1})=f({t_2})$$ from here i'm not getting how to show $t_1=t_2$?

> Source:A Course in Commutative Banach Algebras by Eberhard Kaniuth

Comment: Is anything stopping you from choosing $f$ so that $f(x) = x$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring:But, the relation should hold for all $f\in C^n[a,b]$

Comment: @P.Styles Yes, which means we can choose one of them.

Comment: @BrianMoehring:but this should also hold for any non-identity function also

Comment: And if we can find a single function that shows that $t_1 = t_2$, then it does hold for all of them.  As best I can tell, you are trying to prove $$\forall f \in C^n[a,b], (f(t_1) = f(t_2) \implies t_1 = t_2).$$  This is false, but it's not what you need to prove.  You need to prove $$( \forall f \in C^n[a,b], (f(t_1) = f(t_2))) \implies t_1 = t_2$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring: I was confused ,now i got the feeling ,thank you!!;-)